# How to Properly Import from Blender to Unreal 4?

Tags: objects, export, import, unreal-engine

I am having difficulty importing my ".fbx" from Blender into Unreal Engine 4. The error I am receiving says the model has "degenerate tangent bases, which will result in incorrect shading". Unreal and Blender are fully updated and I have the newest versions. I am on Windows 7 and have tried it on Windows 10 as well as a Mac so I know that isn't the problem. I've tried it on Intel graphics and Nvidia graphics so that isn't it either. Also I tried multiple .fbx versions such as FBX 7.4 binary and FBX 6.1 ASCII already.  I tried different computers that had 4, 6 and 8 GB of RAM.  The processors I ran it on were Intel 2.3 GHz and 3.3 GHz. Also the computers were running at 64 bit. Is Blender compatible with Unreal?  And if so how?  There are no tutorials online that have helped or shown the correct way to import into the Unreal Engine without errors. I've searched high and low across multiple websites for the answer but I have had no luck.  Please help!

Thanks! 
-Rob

Comment: The first few matches googling `"degenerate tangent bases, which will result in incorrect shading"` (keep the quotes) could be of assistance.

Comment: You can also fix it by re-doing your UV in Blender, check that video to know how:
https://youtu.be/25eStIqaYsg

Answer (score 3):

This is just a warning, not an error. It's usually the case when UVs aren't unwrapped well; either there are overlapping UVs, or some UV's are backward. It will still work, and I haven't noticed any problems with shading or texturing on the models I've imported into Unreal.

There is apparently a way to get Unreal to correct some of these problems for you.

From the Unreal forums:

> Double click onto your static mesh in the UE4 -> Select the recompute tangents/normals and click save
>
> [image]